# RabbitMQ database files

Tags: configuration, rabbitmq

I'm running RabbitMQ V.2.0.0. on a Linux machine. The mnesia base is current the default, but the within that directory Rabbit creates directories, eg. rabbit@ip-123.1.1.123.

The ip in the directory name is based on the inet addr of the machine. This directories hold information about user, exchanges, vhost (I think).

My question is, how can I fix/config these directory names with ip to be not based on ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can edit the scripts files (rabbitmq-server, rabbitmq-mulit and rabbitmqcti). In these scripts at the top is a hostname variable.

I set the hostname to localhost and restarted.

This is not the best, but good enough for my requirements. The hostname must be a proper address, it cannot be something arbitrary.

Comment: In addition, you cannot address a RabbitMQ node by its IP address.  i.e. rabbit@localhost - good; rabbit@127.0.0.1 - bad

Answer (score 3):

To change the Mnesia directory, just set MNESIA_DIR in /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf.

Also, a great place to ask RabbitMQ related questions is on the [rabbitmq-discuss](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo) mailing list.

Comment: The root directory isn't the issue. It's the directories within that have caused issues. Because I'm using Amazon EC2 instances the internal IP can change on restart. When that happens I lose my exchanges, queues, vhost, etc.

Comment: This isn't the root directory.  MNESIA_BASE is the root, MNESIA_DIR is normally MNESIA_BASE/NODENAME, but you can overwrite that.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that your new machine has new hostname - and directory is named after it (just renaming directory as mentioned before, does not help) so we need to rename your machine hostname and make RabbitMq to work with old files. 
Let "ip-0-0-0-0" be old machine name (so there should be a mnesia folder */var/lib/rabbitmq/mnsesia/ip-0-0-0-0*), and new machine host 
name is something like "ip-1-1-1-1", but new name doesnot matter as we will overwrite it. Execute following commands:

```
sudo -s
echo "127.0.0.1 ip-0-0-0-0" >> /etc/hosts 
echo "ip-0-0-0-0" > /etc/hostname
reboot
```

After reboot your machine will have a new name and RabbitMq should work with old files.