# Lost messages when migrating RabbitMQ from one EC2 instance to another

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, ec2-ami

I have RabbitMQ installed and working well on an EC2 CentOS 6 instance, with an assortment of queues and topics. I decided to migrate this working instance to another, new EC2 server instance with the same OS and initial setup, just smaller.

I created an AMI (Amazon server image) from the existing installation, and then used this AMI to create a new server instance. RabbitMQ came up just fine, as did all the topics, users, virtual hosts, queues, etc.

However, the queues all came back with 0 messages in them, although messages did exist in the queues before creating the server image.

Questions:

1. Did I miss something in my migration?
2. Where are messages are explicitly 'stored' while they're within rabbit queues?

I believe the messages were sent as 'Persistent' but not 100% sure about that. I am aware of replication of RabbitMQ instances, but figured this method of server recreation would be simpler/quicker?

Comment: If you are not sure if they were persistent messages how can we be sure if they were supposed to be saved or not.  My feeling is that they weren't persistent and therefore were not saved

Comment: @robthewolf - Yup. I agree with your statement. However my question is really around the fact that a (presumably) bit-by-bit clone of one machine didn't re-create on a target machine. So, are non-persistent messages merely stored in transient memory (like RAM)?

Comment: yes. if a message is not persistent it would not have been written to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

@robthewolf's comments got be searching some more but with a slightly different slant (around whether one could explicitly save off queue messages in a backing database/key-value store)

That led me to this old, but seemingly still-relevant blog post that clearly describes rabbit's current 'persistence' methods for all cases (persistent publishing, durable, etc.)

http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/01/20/rabbitmq-backing-stores-databases-and-disks/

Answer (score 0):

If messages were persistent you can check this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889227/rabbitmq-database-files/24979364#24979364) - RabbitMq uses Mnesia storage which is connected to ip address of machine it is running on, so few tweaks in the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979364/1255305) there can resolve the issue.